# Encoding XML with &quot; causing XML document structures issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, post

I am trying to make a POST call using 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' to a 3rd Party service in iOS (objective-c) where one of the form pieces is a XML string. The call itself works and is being received, but the XML has " to replace double quotes and after encoding the service returns this error "XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.". The service can handle the " in other calls from the Android version not the iOS though. Below is a code snippet of how I am making the POST.

```
NSMutableString * data = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat: @"loginPage=page"];
    [data appendString: @"&login=login"];
    [data appendString: @"&password=password"];
    [data appendString: @"&xml="];
    [data appendString: xml];

    xml = [xml stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData * postData = [data dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion: NO];
    NSString * xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: postData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlString);

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"url"]; // eam
    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval: 60];
    [request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: postData];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest: request
                                                                      completionHandler: ^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error)
```

And this is way is being sent. Error coming from 'problem_area' below.

```
loginPage=page&login=login&password=login&xml=
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
<description>OpenRequest</description>
<copyright>words</copyright>
<response service_name="url_call_name" file_type="xml"/>
<client name="client_name" update_database="true">
<work_orders>
<service_wo site_name ="site_name"  problem_area="Bananas 2&quot; - 3&quot;"/> 
</work_orders></client></application>
```

Not able to change the call it is 3rd party also not much information from there end, but I can try to answer any questions. Any help would be much welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of these two calls

```
NSMutableString * data = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat: @"loginPage=page"];
...
xml = [xml stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Well that was it. Time to retire. Thank you, sometimes you just need another set of eyes.

Comment: Welcome. Would it be at all possible to mark the response as done then? Thanks.